# Server warnings on MongoDB startup

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I recently installed MongoDB on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

When I'm starting the MongoDB service, I get some warnings:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.11
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>
```

I think that this is what prevents the migration from Parse.com, as I posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222219/problems-on-migrating-parse-com-app-to-aws-ec2-ubuntu).

How can I ignore these warnings and disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply what MongoDB Docs say:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

I installed MongoDB 3.0.8 as couple of months ago and got the same warnings. This setting was set by Amazon. First thing to do is create a script that can enable and disable Transparent Pages. Documentation gives this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          disable-transparent-hugepages
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:
# X-Start-Before:    mongod mongodb-mms-automation-agent
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Disable Linux transparent huge pages
# Description:       Disable Linux transparent huge pages, to improve
#                    database performance.
### END INIT INFO

case $1 in
  start)
    if [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage ]; then
      thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage
    elif [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage ]; then
      thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage
    else
      return 0
    fi

    echo 'never' > ${thp_path}/enabled
    echo 'never' > ${thp_path}/defrag

    unset thp_path
    ;;
esac
```

I use CentOS. I had this script made and I `chkconfig`'d it as a service so THP is disabled at startup.

In your case, you will have to run the script, restart MongoDB (`service mongod restart`), login to mongo and that warning should be gone. You need to follow the docs for Ubuntu as it says to install using:

```
sudo update-rc.d disable-transparent-hugepages defaults
```

Comment: Don't forget to give permission to the file `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepages`